# Moving elements from one xml file to Another xml file

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I Have two XML files which have the following elements insite them (the item element and its child only) :

```
<warehouse>
   <cat id="computer">
    <item>
      <SN>value</SN>
      <name>value</name>
      <quantity>value</quantity>
      <description>value </description>
      <price>value</price>
    </item>
   </cat>
   <cat id="Stationery">
    <item>
      <SN>value</SN>
      <name>value</name>
      <quantity>value</quantity>
      <description>value </description>
      <price>value</price>
    </item>
   </cat>
</warehouse>
```

//I have here the following code which delete those elements (the item element and its child only).

```
xmlDoc.Root.Descendants("cat").Where(x => x.Attribute("id").Value == "computer")
      .Descendants("item").Where(x => x.Element("SN").Value.Trim() == Dropdownlist.Text)
      .Remove();
xmlDoc.Save(@"YourXML.xml");
```

what I want is to copy these elements from first xml file to the second xml file before deleting them.
how can I do such process using LINQ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily store your query results first, add a copy to other `XDocument` instance and then call `Remove`:

```
var itemsToRemove = xmlDoc.Root.Descendants("cat")
                               .Where(x => x.Attribute("id").Value == "computer")
                               .Descendants("item")
                               .Where(x => x.Element("SN").Value.Trim() == Dropdownlist.Text)
                               .ToList();

// Add is smart enough to perform deep clone of your XML structure on add
otherDoc.Root.Element("cat").Add(itemsToRemove);

itemsToRemove.Remove();

xmlDoc.Save(@"YourXML.xml");
```